# What is the equivalent of sequence.pad_sequences (keras) in CNTK

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, cntk

So I built an LSTM classification model with Keras.

Here is a snippet of my model:

```
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(procprinters, maxlen = 18, padding='post', truncating='post')
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(procprinters, maxlen = 18,  padding='post', truncating='post')



x_train = array(x_train)
print(x_train.shape)
procclass = array(printerclassifcation)

permutations = np.random.permutation(procclass.shape[0])
x_train = x_train[permutations]
y_train = procclass[permutations]



print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(37, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train, validation_split = 0.2, batch_size=5, epoch
```

The code above essentially pads my `X_train and y_train`with 0s in the front with a length of 18. Then I pass that into my model for training. 
Now I am looking to do the same with CNTK. I am unable to understand the documentation online. Can someone please help me with figuring out how to pad my:

```
x_train
y_train
```

as I was using Keras. Any help or guidance is appreciated!